# PHP Mailer doesn't send e-mail

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer ver 6.7.1 to try send a e-mail message. But without success and I can't know why.

This is the error message:

> Erro: [SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: wrobynson@gmail.com: : Client host rejected: Access denied ].

And this is the DEBUG:

```
2023-08-26 11:14:19 Connection: opening to 10.52.202.210:587, timeout=300, options=array ( 'ssl' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ),)
2023-08-26 11:14:19 Connection: opened
2023-08-26 11:14:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mta1.inner.intraer ESMTP Postfix
2023-08-26 11:14:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO siop.cindacta1.intraer
2023-08-26 11:14:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mta1.inner.intraer250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 34603008250-VRFY250-ETRN250-STARTTLS250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250-DSN250 CHUNKING
2023-08-26 11:14:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2023-08-26 11:14:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2023-08-26 11:14:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO siop.cindacta1.intraer
2023-08-26 11:14:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mta1.inner.intraer250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 34603008250-VRFY250-ETRN250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250-DSN250 CHUNKING
2023-08-26 11:14:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<irsys.cindacta1@fab.mil.br>
2023-08-26 11:14:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Ok
2023-08-26 11:14:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<wrobynson@gmail.com>
2023-08-26 11:14:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[10.229.12.60]>: Client host rejected: Access denied
2023-08-26 11:14:19 SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[10.229.12.60]>: Client host rejected: Access denied
2023-08-26 11:14:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2023-08-26 11:14:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
2023-08-26 11:14:19 Connection: closed
SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: wrobynson@gmail.com: <unknown[10.229.12.60]>: Client host rejected: Access denied
```

I noted there is no "CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN" in debug text...

I appreciate if someone can help me.

Thanks.

PS:

This is my code...

```
$MAIL = new PHPMailer(true);

$MAIL->SMTPDebug = 3;

$MAIL->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl'   => array (
                    'verify_peer'       => false,
                    'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
);

$MAIL->From         = "irsys.cindacta1@fab.mil.br";
$MAIL->FromName     = "SIOP";
$MAIL->Host         = "10.52.202.210";  
$MAIL->Port         = "587"; 
$MAIL->Username     = "irsys.cindacta1@fab.mil.br";
$MAIL->Password     = "*******";
$MAIL->SMTPSecure   = "";    //    'TLS' or 'SSL': same error

try {
    $MAIL->IsSMTP();                // set mailer to use SMTP
    $MAIL->IsHTML(true);            // set email format to HTML
    $MAIL->Subject = "Teste de envio de e-mail";
    $MAIL->Body = "Esta é uma mensagem de teste.";
    $MAIL->AddAddress("wrobynson@gmail.com");
    $MAIL->AddReplyTo("no-reply@siop1.decea.mil.br", "NAO RESPONDA");

    $MAIL->Send();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $MAIL->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: It works with ($MAIL->SMTPAuth = true; ) config.

Comment: If you found a solution please add an answer below for the benefit of others and yourself. Answers I'm comments are not searchable. See also [answer]. Glad you fixed it